# I want to check duplication value during insert time without using unique keyword

Tags: laravel-5.6

i make one table for with some column with nullable.

i already tried with two different query. one using

```
Register_member::where('passport',$passport)->orWhere('adharcardnumber',$adharcardnumber)->get();
```

and second DB::table type query.

```
$row = Register_member::where('passport',$passport)->orWhere('adharcardnumber',$adharcardnumber)->get();
if (!empty($row))
{
    return response()->json(["status"=>0, "message"=>"Adharcard or Paasport number already exit."]);
}
if (empty($row))
{
    Register_member::insert(['first_name'=>request('first_name'), 'middle_name'=>request('middle_name'), 'last_name'=>request('last_name'), 'adharcardnumber'=>request('adharcardnumber'), 'ocipcinumber'=>request('ocipcinumber'), 'passport'=>request('passport'), 'birthday'=>request('birthday'),
    'mobilecode'=>request('mobilecode'), 'mobilenumber'=>request('mobilenumber'), 'email'=>request('email'), 'address'=>request('address'), 'landmark'=>request('landmark'), 'area'=>request('area'),
    'gender'=>request('gender'), 'pincode'=>request('pincode'), 'city_name'=>request('city_name'), 'state_id'=>request('state_id'), 'country_id'=>request('country_id'), 'sampraday'=>request('sampraday'), 'other'=>request('other'), 'sms'=>request('sms')]);
    return response()->json(["status"=>1, "message"=>"Member register successful."]);
}
```

if adharcardnumber or passport number are exists in table, then nagetive response. if in both any one in unique then, insert data in table

Comment: did you chack elaquant method firstOrCreate?

Comment: please send me any example because i am new in laravel

Comment: check this out https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent#other-creation-methods

Comment: can i ask you why uh dont using unique validation provided by laravel

Comment: because if i use unique for validation ,then i pass blank values then serve send me nagetive response . i already taken that values .

Comment: i did not get you properly , but why you dont make you own validation class

Comment: i update my whole insert code please check it

Comment: i don't know how to make validation class by own. i use only required field validation and duplication validation that's why

Comment: sorry but i can't update my code

Comment: `Register_member::where('passport',$passport)->orWhere('adharcardnumber',$adharcardnumber)->get();` can give only one row?

Comment: no this condition for passport number or adharcard number duplication. for that what i do

Comment: my mean if its found same thn it will result only one row othervise return empty right

Comment: yes but in my login i return i got only result one row response.

Comment: Register_member::where('passport',$passport)->orWhere('adharcardnumber',$adharcardnumber)->get(); through that query i got only one response passport or adharcard number already exists.

Comment: `$validator = \Validator::make($request->all(), [ 
            'passport' => 'required|unique:tablename,filedname',
//your other validations
        ]);

        if($validator->fails())
        {
         return response()->json(['status'=>400,'error'=>$validator->errors()->all()]);
        }`

Comment: $rules = array(
            'first_name' => 'required',
            'last_name' => 'required',
            'birthday' => 'required',
            'gender' => 'required',
            'mobilecode' => 'required',
            'mobilenumber' => 'required',
            'area' => 'required',
             'adharcardnumber'=>'unique:register_members',
            'passport'=>'unique:register_members',
            'pincode' => 'required',
            'city_name' => 'required',
            'country_id' => 'required',
            'state_id' => 'required' ); i put that validation but not work.

Comment: you need to give field name to in `unique` like `'passport' =>'required|unique:register_members,passport` check my answer

Comment: i send you mail please check it and give me reply as soon as.

Answer (score 0):

Let me suggest you something which I think serve you as a good solution. You can use the unique with required and regex. In this way it will use the already recommended ways of Laravel which are the best.
As an example for your adhaar card,
the validation should look like this

```
 $request->validate([
        'adhaar ' =>['required','unique:users','regex:/\d{12}/'],
    ]);
```

where **adhar** is the filed name where adhaar number is entered. Be sure to use validator like this **use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator;**. Also $request is the instance of the Request.
Using the required prevent empty field submission and the regex will throw an error if the pattern is not matched completely. so I think it would be a better a way to handle the scenario.
the above solution will work in both adhaar and passport. But for the passport the regex will be different though. 
Please note these are all demo examples, you might need to modify it according to your needs. I use *https://www.phpliveregex.com/* for regex making and checking and it is good enough.

I hope you get an idea of how to begin but if you need more information then let me know in the comments.